# Last 10 days Values based on Last available data

Tags: sql, firebird

I have to fetch data from a table in such a way that my start date to fetch data is based on the date where the last data was inserted.

For example I have data from `24/01/2011` to now. But for some specific id we have inserted the last data on `24/01/2012`. In this case for that id I have to fetch the data from `14/01/2012` to `24/01/2012`.

Because I don't know the last date when data was inserted , so first I have to fetch the max of date and based on that I can find the start date. Is there any fast way to do that. So everything is handled in single and fast query.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, answer may look like this:

```
    SELECT *
  FROM table_1 t1
 WHERE table_1.start_date >= to_date('14/01/2012', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
   AND table_1.start_date <=
       (SELECT MAX(t11.insert_date) FROM table_1 t11 WHERE t1.id = t11.id)
```

Comment: I have single column for date(when data is interested). I have to find the data in some date range. But for that range i know that it will be 10 days period but i don't know the range start and end date.So first i have to get the end date then based on period i will get the range.

Comment: the answer above doesn't work as it hard-codes a start date, but the question explicitly indicated the start date required is based on the last data inserted. There was an example of one item which had a most recent insert date of 24/01/2012, and hence the start_date for that item is 14/01/2012, but that is not a fixed start date for all data.

Comment: It dosent't have to hardcode the date. It was just example. You can put there variable that will have correct date. Then it would look like this:  SELECT *
  FROM table_1 t1
 WHERE table_1.start_date >= l_some_date
   AND table_1.start_date <=
       (SELECT MAX(t11.insert_date) FROM table_1 t11 WHERE t1.id = t11.id)

Answer (score 0):

The below query selects all rows where the start date is greater than or equal to the last start date - 10 days. I believe it is correct for firebird

```
 SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.startdate >= dateadd(-10 day to MAX(t1.startdate)
```